# Error function in Python

Tags: python

In Matlab, we can use function

```
error('please try again')
```

to give a error message and exit the program.

Is there a similar function in Python? Thanks.

Comment: Exception handling would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
raise Exception('please try again')
```

Using more informational Exception class is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Rise an [exception](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html), e.g.:

```
raise Exception("please try again")
```